# The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am getting error

"The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database"

I could find few answers but i do lose my data.
I am using Identity 2.0.

What is solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(
null
);
```

into your Application_Start() method in the global.asax file...

(Rename the ApplicationDbContext name to the name you use in your application)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're working with a model that already created the tables, then you changed the model (but no the database), so when it goes and tries to work with the database there is a mismatch between the model and the database.

I don't know if you're working with code first or not, but I suggest you to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer which will update the database automatically to match the changes in the model you've done without loosing data.

Hope it helps. Guillermo.

Comment: Yes but how can we figure out exactly where is the mismatch  ? table name/column/ data type anything ?